# Beautiful blue enigmatic insect (mantid?) in Kenya

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This beautiful insect was found in Kenya today - and we don’t know what it is. We think it may be a mantid of some sort?!

Nairobi kenya, croton trees, cape chestnuts, bougainvilliea, there is quite a lot of lichen on the trees.

Despite looking to be the size of someone's arm, it's about 2” long!
Needless to say, no-one had a good camera at the time. Just phones!

The colour of the insect is very similar to the lichen on the trees (hence the mention above).

Someone suggested it was a 'grizzled mantid' *Gonatista grisea* (Fabricius), but we didn't think they are found native to Kenya - and likewise, we don't see a protuberance on the back of grizzled mantids... Still hoping for an answer.

You can see it also has very small wings, which I hear is a feature of some mantids - micropterous mantids.

I don’t know anything about these - someone said ‘some sort of bark mantis’.

Further update - The pronotum of Tarachodes spp females has two conical tubercles. The males are mostly fully winged, whereas the females often have shortened wings.

So it's probably a female Tarachodes species found in Kenya (or thereabouts).

[image: On a bat]
[image: less blurred]
[image: head - blurred]
[image: in the light]
[image: again]

Comment: I don't have time at the moment for a full answer, but [Patel, S., Singh, G. and Singh, R., 2016. A checklist of global distribution of Liturgusidae and Thespidae (Mantodea: Dictyoptera). Journal of Entomology and Zoology Studies, 4(6), pp.793-803.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311963370_A_checklist_of_global_distribution_of_Liturgusidae_and_Thespidae_Mantodea_Dictyoptera) might be a helpful resource here.

Comment: Actually, the above might be less useful since it looks like some taxonomic reorganization occurred in 2015. I'd recommend exploring [Epaphroditidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaphroditidae)

Comment: @theforestecologist - thanks! I went and checked the references you gave, but supplied photos of those species all looked like mantises, whereas this one doesn’t so much!

Comment: It's indeed nearly the same as a gonatista grisea family Liturgousinae / Liturgusa, perhaps you can msg a mantid forum.

Comment: @aliental, until yesterday I didn’t know there were so many mantids, let alone forae that specialised in them!!

Answer (score 9):

I'm converting my numerous comments into an "answer" -- I don't currently know the exact species, but I can at least explain some of my thoughts more completely.

Your specimen looks a lot like [*Gonatista grisea*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/grizzled_mantid.html), a tree mantis that mimics a lichen -- as you mention in your post. However, *G. grisea*, is native to the southeastern USA. I could find no evidence of any reports finding this species in Africa, so we will rule it out.

If we examine some other species of the [*Gonatista*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonatista) genus (e.g., *G. jaiba, G. major, G. phryganoides, and G. reticulata*) we find that they are all [neotropical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neotropical_realm) and not found in Africa. Therefore, let's look elsewhere.

So, I would recommend examining other close members in the same family that *are* found in Africa.

- I originally recommended reviewing [Patel et al (2016)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311963370_A_checklist_of_global_distribution_of_Liturgusidae_and_Thespidae_Mantodea_Dictyoptera) because they provide a checklist of the global distribution of other members of the [Liturgusidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgusidae) family. Using this guide, we could examine known African genera.

  - They list *Dactylopteryx*, *Majanga* (Madagascar), *Theopompella*, and *Zouza* as African genera.
- However, I had not realized that there had been some taxonomic rearrangements, and *Gonatista* is now in the family [Epaphroditidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaphroditidae).

  - The other genus in the same subfamily as *Gonotista*, *Gonatistella*, is [monotypic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotypic_taxon), and *G. nigropicta* is not your species.
  - The other genera in this family, *Epaphrodita* and *Callimantis*, (as well as the now-moved genus *Brancsikia*) also do not seem to contain any species I could find that are morphologically similar to yours.
- So maybe we should look elsewhere in the previous Liturgusidae...

  - Subtribe Humbertiellina in the [Gonypetidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonypetidae)  family are just one example of another group perhaps worth investigating because it too was once contained within the original Liturgusidae family along with *Gonatista* and because some online evidence suggests some members of this subtribe (e.g., [*Humbertiella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbertiella) and [*Theopompa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theopompa)) share some similar physical characteristics to *Gonatista*.

    - Some non-reputable sources (e.g., [here](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/smooth-edged-bark-mantis-humbertiella-sp-722188051) for *Humbertiella* and [here](https://gramho.com/explore-hashtag/theopompa) and [here](https://gramho.com/explore-hashtag/theopompa) for *Theopompa servillei*) show specimens similar to yours with labels as one of these two genera. I couldn't find consistent imagery or reputable sources with imagery to support either one as correct...
    - (Also, Patel et al. (2016) suggest these genera are recognized as Asian genera, and so they may be geographically unlikely anyway like *Gonatista*).

However, perhaps trying to solve your unknown specimen using taxonomic and trait-similarity approaches could be misleading.

- According to [Rivera (2010)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Julio_Rivera6/publication/281406097_Article_A_historical_review_of_praying_mantid_taxonomy_and_systematics_in_the_Neotropical_Region_State_of_knowledge_and_recent_advances_Insecta_Mantodea/links/55e59a4d08aecb1a7ccc038d/Article-A-historical-review-of-praying-mantid-taxonomy-and-systematics-in-the-Neotropical-Region-State-of-knowledge-and-recent-advances-Insecta-Mantodea.pdf): "*Whereas the [monophyly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophyly) of Mantodea is well supported, the evolutionary relationships within the order are still contentious. Several classification systems for mantids have been proposed...However, the natural affinities among supraspecific taxa have been extremely difficult to discern due to the highly variable and derived morphology of these insects.*"
- According to [Schwarz & Roy (2019)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00379271.2018.1556567): "*As already noticed by previous authors, external morphology is highly [homoplastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoplasy) and does not provide useful systematic tools above subfamily level.*"

[Schwarz & Roy (2019)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00379271.2018.1556567) *do* suggest that the morphology of male external genitalia may be useful for relating individuals as these traits tend to be fairly congruent with more recent molecular phylogenies. You could start there for further research.

- (I myself can't discern meaningful detail of the genitalia in your photos, nor am I any type of expert on mantises, so this route of inquiry might be too much [in the weeds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-the-weeds) for me...)

If you find a good [key](https://collectionseducation.org/identify-specimen/taxonomic-keys/) for your region, you might want to check out [Brannoch et al (2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5673847/) for a "Manual of praying mantis morphology, nomenclature, and practices" to help you with all the mantid jargon. [it appears to be a *very* thorough and excellent resource!].

I will update this post if I find anything more definitive for you...

---

<sup>Citations</sup>

<sup>Brannoch, S.K., Wieland, F., Rivera, J., Klass, K.D., Béthoux, O. and Svenson, G.J., 2017. Manual of praying mantis morphology, nomenclature, and practices (Insecta, Mantodea). *ZooKeys*, (696), p.1.</sup>

<sup>Patel, S., Singh, G. and Singh, R., 2016. A checklist of global distribution of Liturgusidae and Thespidae (Mantodea: Dictyoptera). *Journal of Entomology and Zoology Studies*, 4(6), pp.793-803.</sup>

<sup>Rivera, J., 2010. A historical review of praying mantid taxonomy and systematics in the Neotropical Region: State of knowledge and recent advances (Insecta: Mantodea). *Zootaxa*, 2638(1), pp.44-64.</sup>

<sup>Schwarz, C.J. and Roy, R., 2019, March. The systematics of Mantodea revisited: an updated classification incorporating multiple data sources (Insecta: Dictyoptera). In *Annales de la Société entomologique de France* (NS) (Vol. 55, No. 2, pp. 101-196). Taylor & Francis.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Bark Mantis. Genus Tarachodes.

https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/570572-Tarachodes

Here is a description of the features within the Genus from the link above and why I believe your picture reflects this genus. To narrow down to species appears more challenging as there are many species in the genus:

> The bark mantises and ground mantises (genus Tarachodes) are praying mantids now placed in the family Eremiaphilidae[1] that are native to the Afrotropics. They are generally light brown but more silvery on the wings. The wings are attractively reticulated, and the veins may be mottled dark and pale.[2] The head is wider than the pronotum, which is rounded anteriorly, and doesn't overlap with the rear of the head. The pronotum is depressed, with its sides more or less parallel, and only a weak supra-coxal bulge is present.[3] The anterior tibia are flattened and greatly expanded longitudinally, and the tibial claw does not fit into a pit between the 1st and 2nd external spines of the anterior femora, as in a few mantis groups.[3]

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus inappropriate for this site.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/75814)

Comment: And also, the link points to an proposed identification. It’s definitely in the same area as the OP (Karen) but I am unsure there has yet been a species ID offered. I am pretty sure it is a mantis of some sort - but that is where my quest ran cold!